# Want to install OwnCloud on Netgear wndr3400 Router

Tags: router, network-attached-storage, netgear

I would like to install OwnCloud (http://owncloud.org/) on my Netgear router. It requires PHP and MySQL. I would like to use the router's ReadyShare NAS to share a drive that I would plug in to the USB port and then to run the OwnCloud service from the router itself.

While this may seem unconventional, it also seems like it should be possible since the router does have an underlying web server. I do not have any idea how to access it however, which is why I am asking for help here.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

There's no chance of running mysql. If there's a way to use it with SQLite, it might actually be feasible. You'll have to put DD-WRT on it, following the instructions on [the forum thread for the WNDR3400](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=79102&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=285), recorded here for posterity:

1. Download dd-wrt.v24-18000_NEWD-2_K2.6_mini-WNDR3400.chk
2. Use the Netgear factory software to "Update" to the above download.
3. Boot the router. Breathed sigh of relief when it came up.
4. Configured the Radio and WAN.
5. Downloaded dd-wrt.v24-18946_NEWD-2_K2.6_big-nv64k.bin
6. Updated router to the big version from above.

Then you can ssh in as root and install your packages. Be sure to read EVERYTHING you can find about how to flash (reset everything to defaults via 30-second reset button, reboot, flash, then reset to defaults *again*) and most importantly, about the very real risks of bricking your router and how to reflash if you screw it up. You might have to custom-build a serial cable to reflash it.